# Create a Display Suite Custom Block Field Programatically

Tags: display-suite

Can anyone provide sample code for a custom module and/or provide a reference for hook_ds_fields_info that utilizes 'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_BLOCK, that will actually render in admin/structure/ds/fields.  I'm working in 7.2-2.14 of display suite.

The API documentation appears to be incomplete as listed here:
http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ds%21ds.api.php/function/hook_ds_fields_info/7.

I'm thinking I may be missing some sort of related render function for the block to appear (https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2014/04/02/how-to-create-a-custom-display-suite-field/) however even using this example barebones in a standalone module I don't necessarily get my custom block to show.  I am referencing a custom block initially built out in a custom module.

```
function module_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
  $fields = array();

  $fields['title'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Custom Module'),
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_BLOCK,
    'ui_limit' => array('article|*', 'audience_page|*', 'overview_page|*', 'page|*', 'product|*', 'product_overview|*'),
    'properties' => array(
      'block' => 'my_custom_module',
      'block_render' => DS_BLOCK_CONTENT,
    ),
  );

  return array('node' => $fields);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already reported in [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds/issues/2539092) DS issue, you need to alter DS_BLOCK_CONTENT to DS_BLOCK_TEMPLATE.

We had a similar issue where from a certain point in time, the block was no longer rendered.
That point in time was a security update on the DS module, we applied somewhere a month ago : 
https://www.drupal.org/sa-contrib-2018-019